# Chamar um método de uma DLL .NET C# de uma aplicação ASP Clássico

Tags: c#, .net, asp

Tenho um sistema web em ASP que faz o gerenciamento de armazem (WMS). O sistema funciona e já está em uso em algumas empresas.

Recentemente surgiu a necessidade de trabalhar com etiquetas que serão coladas nos volumes do pedido. A impressora que vou utilizar é uma Zebra Térmica.

Eu tenho uma DLL e o fonte dela em C# que já utilizo em sistemas para windows (VB) e funciona muito bem. Porém o meu problema está em fazer com que os métodos dessa mesma DLL sejam reconhecidos pelo meu sistema ASP (IIS).

Consigo instanciar o objeto da DLL com o seguinte comando no ASP *Server.CreateObject("PrintZebra.RawPrinterHelper")* sem qualquer erro. Mas ao tentar acessar o método que vai enviar as strings para a impressora Zebra, o IIS retorna Que o Objeto objZebra não dá suporte para o método *SendStringToPrinter*.

O código C# que usei para compilar a DLL segue abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

//[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
//[assembly: Guid("6c87161d-1e02-40ef-8512-82f30bc1ae3e")]
namespace PrintZebra
{
    //[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Classe 
    /// </summary>
    public class RawPrinterHelper

    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = ".NET RAW Document";
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            //dwCount = szString.Length;joao
            dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            bool bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Int32 dwError = 0;
            if (bSuccess == false)
               {
                  dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
               }
               Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return dwError;
        }            

    }
}
```

No ASP eu utilizo o seguinte código para instanciar o objeto e tentar acessar o método:

```
Dim objZebra    
set objZebra = Server.CreateObject("Opus127Etiquetas.RawPrinterHelper")

objZebra.SendStringToPrinter
```

É importante dizer que todas as permissões da DLL estão OK, tanto que consigo acessar seus métodos em um novo projeto no VS 2015 adicionando-a como referência.

Pesquisei em muitos forums, li artigos e as respostas que encontrei é que meus métodos estão setados como *estáticos* e por isso o COM Interop não consegue reconhecê-los.

A questão é que não sei como transformar esses métodos estáticos em não estáticos, e esta a razão de eu estar abrindo este tópico aqui no StackOverflow.

Alguém já passou por isso e saberia me dar um norte para tentar solucionar o problema?

Comment: Um método estático não fica disponível para você acessar pela instância do objeto que você criou com o `CreateObject`. Já tentou criar um método público não estático na classe `RawPrinterHelp` e dentro dele chamar o método estático que faz a operação?

Comment: @Pagotti Então, quando criei este post aqui eu meio que já sabia que o que eu tinha que fazer era exatamente isto, porém não sabia como. Existe também este mesmo post que criei no StackOverflow em inglês onde digo que após muita pesquisa e trabalho duro consegui resolver o problema. Ainda não respondi aqui porque estou esperando para ver se alguém se habilita. Segue o post original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974360/call-net-c-sharp-dll-method-from-classic-asp

Comment: Tranquilo. O importante é que já tem uma solução.